# Access VBA: Syntax error on WHERE clause, possible type conflict?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to run this piece of code:

```
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ORDER_DATA WHERE ORDER=" & curOrder
    Set rst_orderData = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

The ORDER column from ORDER_DATA is a double number type, and curOrder is of type double as well.

The error I'm getting points to the second line and says "Syntax error on WHERE clause".

Why do you think this is? Is it a possible type conflict?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Why yave you named a variable of type double with the prefix generally used for currency? Why not `dblOrder`? That's obviously not the problem, as currency is implicitly coerceable to double and you're not getting a type mismatch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ORDER` is reserved word, as in `ORDER BY`. You have to put it in brackets.

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ORDER_DATA WHERE [ORDER]=" & curOrder
```